# Custom Facebook tab with different urls passed at creation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that several similar questions has been asked but I still do not understand how to implement this.

I just need each of my users who install my custom tab to have their tab point to a unique url of my website (their profile page).

I know the url at the moment they install the tab :

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'pagetab',
  redirect_uri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
}, function(response){});
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can’t. There is only one page tab URL per app. You can get the id of the page your app is currently running on from the signed_request (research please), and then display different content or redirect to a different page inside your app based on that.

Comment: Oh! Then I see why I couldn't do it. Thank you very much!